# Set plot (axes) view "box" without affecting limits

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a 2D plot with many data elements on it covering a extensive area. Although all the data is necessary, I am usually interested on a small element of the plot.
I would like to programmatically focus the view on that element of interest, while allowing to use the zoom tool ((-) in the GUI) to fastly go back to a wider perspective.

It is easy to use `set(gca, 'xlim', [limitsXOfSmallElement])` and `set(gca, 'ylim', [limitsYOfSmallElement])` to set axis limits so that the small element is in focus, but this makes  impossible to use the GUI (-) zoom tool to go back to the general view without manually resetting back axis limits to original values.

My intuition is that this could be solved by controlling camera properties (`CameraPosition`, `CameraTarget` and/or `CameraViewAngle`), but when I apply them, posterior uses of the GUI zoom tool have weird effects on the axis, as changing its position and size on the figure.

Is there a good method for setting the fragment of the 2D canvas that is displayed in the axis?

Comment: I would guess the correct combination of `zoom` and `pan` would work for you?

Comment: You're probably right, @Dan, but the bizarre side effects when I started zooming around in the GUI really discouraged me to keep on trying that option. Anyway, if I try that in the future and find a solution I'll post it here for reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following example:

```
function example_zoom
    %# some plot
    plot(1:10)
    hAx = gca;

    %# save original axis limits
    setappdata(hAx, 'limits',get(gca,{'XLim','YLim'}))

    %# create custom toolbar button
    [X,map] = imread(fullfile(toolboxdir('matlab'),'icons','view_zoom_out.gif'));
    icon = ind2rgb(X,map);
    uipushtool('CData',icon, 'ClickedCallback',{@click_cb,hAx});

    %# zoom
    uiwait(msgbox('Zooming now, click button to reset', 'modal'))
    set(gca, 'XLim',[3 7], 'YLim',[2 9])
    %zoom on
end

function click_cb(o,e, hAx)
    %# restore original axis limits
    limits = getappdata(hAx, 'limits');
    set(hAx, 'XLim',limits{1}, 'YLim',limits{2})
end
```

The idea is to create your own [toolbar button](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uipushtool.html) that restores the axis limits to their original values.

[image: plot]

Comment: Worked like a charm. It is a kind of a workaround but has no negative side :D